# Magento2 - MSI In-Store Pickup how to enable?

Tags: magento2.3.2, msi

I have a fresh Magento 2.3.2 installation and want to allow my customers to pick up their orders in-store.

But I can't find any configuration related to this functionality, can someone explain to me, how to configure In-Store Pickup in Magento?

Comment: There is no any store pickup default I think sir.
But you can do it via third party extensions.

Comment: @Mayur what about this https://github.com/magento/inventory/wiki/Support-of-Store-Pickup-for-Multi-Source-Inventory ?

Comment: Sorry sir my mistake.

Comment: do you know how to enable now?

Comment: @niceonelee no, this answer is still open

Comment: @underser if you know please tell me too, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The MSI In-Store Pickup is not released yet.
The public release will be in MSI 1.2 (Magento 2.4).

There is a [demo link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-na0X-357Dk) which contains an answer to your question.

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

In the Magento Shipping configuration, set Enable Click and Collect to “Yes”.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/magento-shipping-click-collect.html

Comment: As far as I understand this is for **Magento Shipping**, as of my point of view, the same thing must exist for ex. for **Free Shipping**, or have to be separate shipping method something like **In-Store Pickup**. Am I missing something?

Comment: please read the docs about shipping. not just this one page

Comment: The answer is not relevant. Please see [my reply](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/303540/45573).

Answer (score 0):

The In-Store delivery method is included with MSI 1.2: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/shipping-in-store-delivery.html

Answer (score 0):

I have followed all the steps in the guideline  but the in-store delivery method is still not displayed in the frontend. I am using version 2.4.2